# How do I use mergesort to sort the names that have the same surname?

Tags: c, mergesort

Our instructor gave us a csv file where we should sort the names alphabetically based on their surnames.
But there are names with the same surname and
my code only works for their surname.
I don't know what to add to sort them by their first names when they have the same surname.

This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define people 11

struct list_people {
    char FirstName[20];
    char LastName[20];
    char Name[20];
    char Age[5];
};

typedef struct list_people Details;

int merge_sort();
int merge(Details *[11], int, int, int);

int main() {
    FILE *info;
    int i, j;
    Details A[people];
    Details *cell[people];
    
    for (i = 0; i < (people + 1); i++) {
       cell[i] = &A[i];
    }
    
    info = fopen("people.csv", "r");
    for (i = 0; i < people; i++) {
       fscanf(info," %[^,], %[^,], %8s", A[i].LastName, A[i].FirstName, A[i].Age);
    }
    fclose(info);
    
    merge_sort(cell, 1, people - 1);
    for (i = 1; i < people; i ++) {
        printf( "\t %-20s %-20s Age:%-20s \n", A[i].FirstName, A[i].LastName, A[i].Age);
    }
}
    
int merge_sort(Details *A[], int low, int high) {
    int mid;
    if (low < high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        merge_sort(A, low, mid);
        merge_sort(A, mid + 1, high);
        merge(A, low, mid, high);
    }
    return 0;
}
    
int merge(Details *A[], int low, int mid, int high) {
    int leftIndex = low;
    int rightIndex = mid + 1;
    int combinedIndex = low;
    int i, j;
    Details tempA[people];
    
    while (leftIndex <= mid && rightIndex <= high) {
        if (strcasecmp((A[leftIndex]->LastName), (A[rightIndex]->LastName)) <= 0) {
            tempA[combinedIndex] = *(*(A + leftIndex));
            combinedIndex++;
            leftIndex++;
        } else {
            tempA[combinedIndex] = *(*(A + rightIndex));
            combinedIndex++;
            rightIndex++;
        }
    }
    if (leftIndex == mid + 1) {
        while (rightIndex <= high) {
            tempA[combinedIndex] = *(*(A + rightIndex));
            combinedIndex++;
            rightIndex++;
        }
    } else {
        while (leftIndex <= mid) {
            tempA[combinedIndex] = *(*(A + leftIndex));
            combinedIndex++;
            leftIndex++;
        }
    }
    
    for (i = low; i <= high; i++) {
       *(*(A + i)) = tempA[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

You could compare the elements using something like this:

```
        int cmp;
        // compare the last names
        cmp = strcasecmp( ( A[leftIndex]->LastName), ( A[rightIndex]->LastName) );
        if (cmp == 0)
        {
            // last names are identical so compare the first names
            cmp = strcasecmp( ( A[leftIndex]->FirstName), ( A[rightIndex]->FirstName) );
        }
        if (cmp <= 0)
        {
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in the code:

- the array size is `people`, so the initialization loop should exclude the index value `people`. Instead of `for (i = 0; i < (people + 1); i++)` you should write:

  ```
    for (i = 0; i < people; i++)
  ```
- to avoid buffer overflows, you should specify the maximum number of bytes to read for each destination array in `fscanf()`:

  ```
    fscanf(info," %19[^,], %19[^,], %4s", A[i].LastName, A[i].FirstName, A[i].Age);
  ```

  You should also check the return value of `fscanf()` to detect invalid input.
- to order items that have the same last name, you should use a comparison function and compare `LastName`, then `FirstName`, then `Age`, returning the first non-equal result.

Here is an example:

```
int compareDetails(const Details *a, const Details *b) {
    int res, age_a, age_b;
    if ((res = strcasecmp(a->LastName, b->LastName)) != 0)
        return res;
    if ((res = strcasecmp(a->FirstName, b->FirstName)) != 0)
        return res;
    age_a = atoi(a->Age);
    age_b = atoi(a->Age);
    return (age_a > age_b) - (age_a < age_b);
}
```

Arrays are zero based in C, so index values should start at `0`. It is also idiomatic in C to specify an array slice with the first index included and the last index excluded. This allows for empty slices and make the `merge_sort` code simpler, avoiding error-prone `+1`/`-1` adjustments.

The `cell` pointer array is redundant since you sort the array of `Details` in place. You can simplify the code this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PEOPLE 11

struct list_people {
    char FirstName[20];
    char LastName[20];
    char Name[20];
    char Age[5];
};

typedef struct list_people Details;

int merge_sort(Details A[], int low, int high);

int main() {
    FILE *info;
    int i, j, n;
    Details A[PEOPLE];
    
    info = fopen("people.csv", "r");
    if (info == NULL)
        return 1;

    for (n = 0; n < PEOPLE; n++) {
       if (fscanf(info," %19[^,], %19[^,], %4s", A[n].LastName, A[n].FirstName, A[n].Age) != 3)
           break;
    }
    fclose(info);
    
    merge_sort(A, 0, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf( "\t %-20s %-20s Age:%-20s \n", A[i].FirstName, A[i].LastName, A[i].Age);
    }
    return 0;
}
    
int compareDetails(const Details *a, const Details *b) {
    int res, age_a, age_b;

    if ((res = strcasecmp(a->LastName, b->LastName)) != 0)
        return res;
    if ((res = strcasecmp(a->FirstName, b->FirstName)) != 0)
        return res;
    age_a = atoi(a->Age);
    age_b = atoi(a->Age);
    return (age_a > age_b) - (age_a < age_b);
}

void merge(Details A[], int low, int mid, int high) {
    int leftIndex = low;
    int rightIndex = mid;
    int combinedIndex = 0;
    int i, j;
    Details tempA[high - low];
    
    while (leftIndex < mid && rightIndex < high) {
        if (compareDetails(&A[leftIndex], &A[rightIndex]) <= 0) {
            tempA[combinedIndex] = A[leftIndex];
            combinedIndex++;
            leftIndex++;
        } else {
            tempA[combinedIndex] = A[rightIndex];
            combinedIndex++;
            rightIndex++;
        }
    }
    while (leftIndex < mid) {
        tempA[combinedIndex] = A[leftIndex];
        combinedIndex++;
        leftIndex++;
    }
    while (rightIndex < high) {
        tempA[combinedIndex] = A[rightIndex];
        combinedIndex++;
        rightIndex++;
    }
    for (i = low; i < high; i++) {
        A[i] = tempA[i - low];
    }
}

int merge_sort(Details A[], int low, int high) {
    if (high - low >= 2) {
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        merge_sort(A, low, mid);
        merge_sort(A, mid, high);
        merge(A, low, mid, high);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two equal last names, then you need to compare against another attribute and use *that* to determine which way to sort.

First, to make things a bit more legible, we're going to take the calls to `strcasecmp` out of the condition expressions and save their result to some variable:

```
while ( leftIndex <= mid  &&  rightIndex <= high )
{
  int lastNameResult = strcasecmp( A[leftIndex]->LastName, A[rightIndex]->LastName );
```

Then as a first pass we're going to split the `<= 0` case into two separate cases:

```
  if ( lastNameResult < 0 )
  {
    // left < right, process as before
  }
  else if ( lastNameResult == 0 )
  {
    // new case to handle same last names
  }
  else
  {
    // left > right, process as before 
  }
```

Now within this new case, we need compare against a second attribute; the usual choice would be `FirstName`:

```
  ...
  else if ( lastNameResult == 0 )
  {
    int firstNameResult = strcasecmp( A[leftIndex]->FirstName, A[rightIndex]->FirstName );

    if ( firstNameResult < 0 )
    {
      // left < right, handle the same way you did for LastName
    }
    else if ( firstNameResult == 0 )
    {
      // left == right, need to compare against another attribute
    }
    else
    {
      // left > right, handle the same way you did for LastName
    }
  }
  ...
```

If you run into two entries with the same first names, then you would need to pick *another* attribute to compare against (such as `Age`), and put that in the `else if ( firstNameResult == 0 )` branch.  Alternately, you can merge the `<` and `==` cases and just let duplicate entries fall where they fall.

Obviously this approach doesn't scale very well for more than a couple of attributes, and you wind up duplicating code.  A better way to do this is to decouple the comparisons from the merges.  Add a new variable, we'll call it `mergeLeft`, that's set to true (nonzero) if you need to merge from the left list, false (`0`) if you need to merge from the right.  We can compute this *without* needing to use a whole if-else chain:

```
while ( leftIndex <= mid  &&  rightIndex <= high )
{
  int lastNameResult = strcasecmp( A[leftIndex]->LastName, A[rightIndex]->LastName );
  int firstNameResult = strcasecmp( A[leftIndex]->FirstName, A[rightIndex]->FirstName );

  /**
   * Yes, you can use logical expressions outside of an if condition.  The
   * parentheses aren't necessary in this case, but it should make the
   * expression easier to understand.  The result of this expression
   * will either be 0 or 1.  
   */
  int mergeLeft = lastNameResult < 0 || (lastNameResult == 0 && firstNameResult < 0);
```

The `mergeLeft` variable will be set to true (`1`) if the left `LastName` is less than the right `LastName`, *or* if the last names are equal and the left `FirstName` is less than the right `FirstName`.  Poof, that ugly nested `if` statement magically goes away, and we're left with this as the body of your `while` loop:

```
  if ( mergeLeft )
  {
    tempA[combinedIndex++] = *A[leftIndex++];  // I've combined the updates
  }                                            // of combinedIndex and leftIndex
  else                                         // within these statements, 
  {                                            // just to save a little space
    tempA[combinedIndex++] = *A[rightIndex++]; // I also replaced pointer
  }                                            // notation with array notation
}                                              // because it's less eye-stabby
```